# Elastic Search must and Should Combination

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I'm new to elastic search and I've the below data in ElasticSearch.

```
    {
        "User": "A",
        "Event": "E1"
    },
    {
        "User": "A",
        "Event": "E2"
    }
    {
        "User": "A",
        "Event": "E3"
    },
    {
        "User": "A",
        "Event": "E4"
    }
```

Now I want to fetch data like below i.e

**(Event='E1') AND (Event='E2'OR Event='E3' OR Event='E4')**

I went through elastic search doc and found that should is used as OR and must is used as AND but I'm a bit confused about how can I form the query.

I used the below query:-

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 10,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "Event": "E1"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "match": {
                                    "Event": "E2"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "match": {
                                    "Event": "E3"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "match": {
                                    "Event": "E4"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

But the output is not as expected.
The help is appreciated thanks in advance!!!

Comment: You have a array? Provide the mapping index.

Comment: @rabbitbr No, It's not an array. modifying the question. I just preparing the data to paste into the question

Comment: Wich output you expected?

Comment: I'm getting blank when i tried above query

Comment: this happens because there is no way for the clause to be true (event=E1 and (event=E2 or event=E3 or ...)).

Comment: the options is use only OR.

Comment: There is a missing piece in your question. 

If it is not an array (each user is an individual document) then why not setting a should E1, E2, E3, E4 ? there is no way to do this AND if each document can only contain 1 Event.

Comment: Each document contains the different event